# Why does a process create a zombie if execv fails, but not if execv is successful and terminates?

Tags: c, fork, child-process

So I am confused by the behavior of my C program. I am using the construct,

```
int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    if(file_upload_script_path) {
        rc = execv(file_upload_script_path, args);
        if(rc == -1) {   
            printf("Error has occured when starting file_upload.exp!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    } else {   
        printf("Error with memory allocation!\n");
    }
}
else {
    printf("pid=%d\n", pid);
}
```

To fork the process and run a script for doing file upload. The script will by itself terminate safely, either by finishing the upload or failing.

Now, there was a problem with the script path, causing `execv` to fail. Here I noted the child process will terminate successfully if execv finishes, but in case it fails (r==-1) and I exit the process, it will become a zombie. Anyone knows why this happens?

Note here, I know why the child-process becomes a zombie. What I am confused about is why the process not becomes a zombie if execv works.

**EDIT:**

I got a question about errno and the cause of the error. The cause of the error is known. There were a problem with the build process, so the path of the script were another than expected.

However, this may happen again and I want to make sure my program does not start spawning zombies when it does. The behavoir where zombies are created in some situations and not others are very confusing.

BR
Patrik

Comment: And what is the value of errno?

Comment: @KamilCuk errno? Do you mean the error code of execv? Would this no be rc? Or better question, using the errno.h, how would this solve things practically?

Comment: It's not safe to call `exit()` after a failed `exec()` in a child process.  One of the things `exit()` does is flush all buffered streams, and since the child process is a copy of the parent process and contains a copy of any data that the parent had buffered when `fork()` was called, the **child** process will then flush that data into the **parent's** files.  You need to call the POSIX `_exit()` or standard C `_Exit()` function instead.

Comment: From [man execv](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv): `The return value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.` errno is set to indicate the error. Och, I see the edit. But you have to reap the child no matter if you call execv or not, not to create a zombie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create zombies, your program has to reap zombie processes no matter if they call `execv` or not call it or no matter if the `execv` call succeeds. To reap zombie processes "automagically" handle SIGCHLD signal:

```
void handle_sigchld(int sig) {
    int saved_errno = errno;
    while (waitpid((pid_t)(-1), 0, WNOHANG) > 0) {}
    errno = saved_errno;
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGCHLD, handle_sigchld);
    // rest of your program....
}
```

Inspired (no... ripped off) from: [this link](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reap_zombie_processes_using_a_sigchld_handler.html).

Or maybe you want only to reap only this specified child, because later you want to call `fork()` and handle childs return value. Then pass the returned `pid` from `fork()` in your parent to the signal handler and `wait` on this pid in sigchld if needed (with some checking, ex. if the pid already finished then ignore future SIGCHLD etc...).

Comment: Thanks Kamil. I will try this. However, I expect it will work. This script may be called several times, but it is supposed to handle itself. So basically I do not need to track the pids.

Comment: Like a charm :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, when the execv fails, the child process is killed. The fun part, I think is what happens when you call exec family of functions.

The exec family of functions replaces the current image of the process with the new image of the binary you are about to exec.

So, whatever code *was* will not *remain* - and the error in your script would cause its death.

Here, the parent needs to listen on the death of the child process using wait flavour of functions (read: waitpid).

When you say that there's problem in the script, it means that the execv actually succeeded in creating the new image; but the latter failed of its own accord.

This is what I think is happening...

**If the printf of if (rc==-1) is being executed, then perhaps changing exit(0) to _exit(0) should take care of it.**

Comment: was the printf in the if(rc == -1) getting executed?

Comment: Yes, the printout got executed. As I said, the parent process seems to wait for the sigterm signal when execv fails, but not when it worked. It is not a problem for my app if the script dies. These are two separate behaviors managing themselves.

Comment: Also, the zombies occurs when the progam fails to start. Generally I would assume all child processes would create zombies, but for some reason there are none when execv starts.

Comment: In that case, I think, _exit(0) should take care of it instead of exit (0); Worth a try?

Comment: Actually, when a child process dies it will remain in the process table until the parent have collected the exit status (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zombie-processes-prevention/). I did not know this at first, but know now. About the execv, it seems as if the process called using execv gets detached somehow (as it keeps running if the parent is killed).